# Import mysql table to XML file

Tags: mysql, xml

I have a website for school project, written in html,jsp and I use mysql as database for users info.
I have a pretty simple and basic knowledge of mysql and barely of php and everywhere I search they use php for that and I don't really understand.
I have a database called "a1" and in that a table called "members". I use ubuntu 10.10 if that matters.

So, how do I import a table in mysql to a XML file?

Iknow it's a big request but explanations or links to some would be great :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is just 'import to xml' once,  one option is to use mysqldump from the command line.

```
mysqldump --xml
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html

MysqlDump dumps the contents of the tables to stdout, and can be piped to a file

```
mysqldump --xml -u user -p a1 members > a1_members.xml
```

Comment: mysqldump --xml a1 members -u root -p
 || looked like it did something but where it saved it? how do I decide the tags or order? a bit more explanation would be great..

Comment: Added a bit about saving the contents.  Looking over the manual, it appears that sort by primary key is the only option.  "--order-by-primary"  Tag order is according to the table structure.  Anything more specific and your looking at whipping something up in Java / JSP or a learning curve for a different language such as XSLT